# Showing labels as they will be printed/exported in my print layout?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, print-composer, qgis-print-layouts

I set up a print layout for a map I want to print in QGIS. Some of my layers have labels on them. When I zoom in and out in the screen, without changing anything else on the print layout, some labels shift position relative to the page and other features. (Sometimes they even appear or disappear.) I am **not** zooming inside the map, I am zooming the view of the entire layout.

The thing is, when I print the layout to paper, the labels won't move when I move my eyes closer or further from the page. I'd like to see in the QGIS print layout what the labels will look like when printed. How can I do this? I'm fine with QGIS choosing where to place the labels. I just want it to be consistent in the Print Layout with what will actually be printed.

I couldn't find any options that sounded like they would change this on QGIS 3.10.1. I tried locking the layers and/or the map item, and that only did what it'd be expected to do; it did not change the behavior of the labels. I looked around for a "symbology scale" option and found none. Am I missing something?

Comment: That might be a bug. I don't think the labels are supposed to change places when changing the the print layout zoom level. I suggest making a [bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues).

Comment: @csk thanks for the suggestion. I did so [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33560).

Comment: As a workaround, you could try using data-defined label placement. That should give every label a fixed placement, although it's hard to predict whether it will resolve an issue caused by a bug.

Comment: @csk thanks, yes, it looks like pinning labels to data-defined positions & rotations, and turning off any option that might let it change the visibility, will be a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Layer Properties dialog for the given layer.

Activate the Rendering tab.

Enable scale-based rendering by clicking on the checkbox labeled Scale dependent visibility:

Change the Minimum value to 1:10000.

See attached screenshot showing Scale Dependent Visibility:

[image: Properties tab Rendering]